# ASP.NET MVC - Encrypt URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, encryption

I'm developing a Web Site using ASP.NET MVC 3, Nowadays I need to encrypt the ID of my customer's URL. For example:

```
http://mysite.com/person?id=42
```

to something like that:

```
http://mysite.com/person?id=Dfjhasdfh33kASDG868365çkhg54sdSDFD
```

It need be secure. 
When I say secure, It means hard to any one discover the correct ID

Is there any library to do that?

Many secure web payments one of then like paypal uses this type of approach:
https://paypal.com/br/webscr?info=CNS9tFsVM_tv4c18gHgZ3OMH2zblN7GWDQoyamVF3mzNh7vGDuhiKU3

Comment: Define the "secure" scope of your project.

Comment: Try this post, and hopfully it will answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157150/mvc3-encrypted-querystring-parameters

Comment: What does this user id represent? Is it the current user? Why does it need to be secure? What could happen if it is not encrypted?

Comment: When I say secure, It means hard to any one discover the correct ID.

Comment: But why it should be hard to discover? What are the consequences? Why doesn't Forms Authentication fit your scenario? Why the user id has to be part of the url at all? There are many questions that need to be answered if you expect a good advice and one that's adapted to your actual requirement (and please don't say that your actual requirement is to encrypt the id query string parameter).

Comment: Many secure web payments one of then like paypal uses this type of approach:
https://paypal.com/br/webscr?info=CNS9tFsVM_tv4c18gHgZ3OMH2zblN7GWDQoyamVF3mzNh7vGDuhiKU3

And yes! This is a requirement!

Comment: What makes your long ID any more secure than the number? This sounds like security through obscurity.

Comment: So what if somebody tries to use ?id=41 It's up to you to make sure people can not access that page. Encrypting the url is solving the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you REALLY want to encrypt the query param, it's very simple, just use any encryptor provided by .Net and then use an attribute or a httpmodule to decrypt the param.

The most important thing is to ALWAYS validate the request. If you can do it a POST with anti forgery token, do it. Then, always check the user credentials if that user has access to the protected resource.

It's not hard at all, but you have to take it slowly and handle every scenario you can think of. Use a white list approach: only those who meet some conditions are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to make your PK's that long with a randomly generated string or a unique identifier (GUID).

Comment: But to queries over those GUID will take long times.

Comment: It is possible to generate GUIDs nowadays that are sequential and thus PK friendly. If sequential means that they are somewhat "predictable" and that's not acceptable, you could add a surrogate key column for this guid and use a non-clustered index.